# KDE consider programs as libraries (.so), How to change file assotiation for program?

Tags: kde, executable, file-format

### Question:

How to make the correct file extension association in KDE so programs are executable from the UI?

> Linux 4.9 Debian 9 (stretch) stable version 64bit 2017-09-28.
>   KDE Plasma as included by default

### Context:

I recently installed the latest stable Debian, and KDE seem to consider every executable as (.so) libraries. This is an issue when I click on a software (binary file in dolphin) and it open the dialog for "*Select the program you want to use to open the file* "

The program has `ugo+x` permissions so I guess is KDE misconfiguration.

Following is a screen capture, if that may be a better explanation.
https://youtu.be/O_nJX6JJV-E

Answer (score 0):

You do not start any program with a magic wand. While using CLI (command line interface = console) the shell program is running and you put down some commands - if you write a valid name of a program, the shell program loads this into the memory and start it. While working in Xwindows, pointing the "mouse" to a program file, you have to know what kind of prog. it is (binary, shell script, python, perl ...), and what do you want to do it with (run, edit). For running the python script, it seems to be usefull to choose python as the preffered application. In some caces, it is easier to open an xterm in a window, and start the program using CLI. In the case you want to edit a script, the preffered application could be the Kate, Kwrite or any other text editor even IDE.

Comment: It is a binary executable, not a script. Nothing you want to edit manually neither.(ELF format)

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried right click on the file and choose "Properties"? There is button with st. like "File type options" (I am not sure with the English name). There you can set up the applications priority chain.

Comment: Sorry: you missed the "+ Add" button to set up the preferred application to open the file. (I saw the video lately)

Comment: What is the preferred application for a program?